# How to instantiate an empty element with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I use JAXB to create XML messages. The XML I need to create is (for the sake of simplicity):

```
<request>
  <header/>
</request>
```

My code looks like this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "request")
public class Request {

    private String header;

    @XmlElement(required=true)
    public String getHeader() {
      return header;
    }

    public void setHeader(String header) {
      this.header=header;
    }
}
```

The problem: the `header` element is not displayed (header is `null`). When header is set to an empty string, the following is displayed:

```
<request>
  <header></header>
</request>
```

When I use as type `Object` instead of `String`, the result is even worse:

```
<request>
  <header xsi:type="xs:string" 
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"></header>
</request>
```

BTW: I'm using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590405/generic-method-in-java-without-generic-argument/590418#590418) to create the XML string.

Is it possible to get an empty tag?

Comment: So what is wrong with setting header to ""?

Comment: I want <header/> and not <header></header>.

Comment: @doekman Ehm, I know it's late, but just in case. To do EXACTLY what you want, you can use [EclipseLink MOXy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation of JAXB, which has a very nice extension `@XmlNullPolicy`. See an example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11748678/814702) (in the "Option #2" section)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In XML, `<header/>` and `<header></header>` are the same thing. If you really want the former, then use a prettifier. `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newTransformer()` will probably do that for you.

Comment: Hi @Tom. Could you explain a bit more in details how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

An empty tag for a String object is essentially the empty string.

If you call the following, you will get what you are looking for:

```
request.setHeader("")
```

I should also note that in XML the following two declarations of a header are idential. Both of these have no child text nodes. These are essentially the same and will be treated the same by all XML parsers:

```
<header></header>

<header/>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, what if one wants to create an empty tag for wrapper objects like Boolean, BigInteger, BigDecimal, etc? Apparently setting null to those will result in the tags not being generated.

Answer (score 2):

As @Tom Hawtin - tackline said

`<header/>` and `<header></header>` is same. Parsers will give you "".

You have to to put `nillable` on your header annotation

```java
@XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true)
public String getHeader() {
  return header;
}
```

I hope this code will generate following XML for `null` value.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Request {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        final Request request = new Request();
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Request.class);
        final Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,
                               Boolean.TRUE);
        marshaller.marshal(request, System.out);
        System.out.flush();
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable=true, required=true)
    private String header;
}
```

prints

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<request>
    <header xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</request>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same thing, effectively `<header/>` rather than `<header></header>`
during the xml serialization process.

Since a null value - rather than an empty string - will produce the correct result, I modified my setter method to set the value explicitly to null:

```
public void setHeader(String header) {
    this.header = "".equals(header) ? null : header;
}
```