# How to marshal empty string to a single tag

Tags: xml, jaxb, marshalling

I've my object, configured with the code:

```
object.setName("");
```

marshaled into following XML:

```
<object>
    <name></name>
</object>
```

But I want single tag:

```
<object>
    <name/>
</object>
```

Is it easy to do with JAXB for all my objects at once?

**UPDATE**

Similar question:
[How to instantiate an empty element with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594537/how-to-instantiate-an-empty-element-with-jaxb)

It's suggested to use prettifier javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newTransformer(), but without explanation how to use it. Ideally my goal is to get exact code to configure JAXB to get the desired result.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/594537/how-to-instantiate-an-empty-element-with-jaxb

Comment: Hi @James, that's very similar, but the subject is a bit different plus there is no detailed explanation how to user prettifier, so let me keep this question open. I will update the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was found in another question [How to instantiate an empty element with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594537/how-to-instantiate-an-empty-element-with-jaxb) where it's suggested to either use a prettifier or don't do anything at all because both versions of XML are equivalent.