# Invoking statically imported method with explicit type parameters

Tags: java, generics

This is the follow up of my question here: [Weird Java generic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050202/weird-java-generic).

If I have a code like this:

```
Casts.<X, T> cast(iterable[index]);
```

Can I add a static import and do:

```
<X, T> cast(iterable[index]);
```

Eclipse doesn't allow this. But after seeing so many bugs with static import in Eclipse, I'm not that certain.

Comment: It will be grate, if one day there would be possible to write method type parameters after method name. E.g. `cast<Lion, Animal>(someLion)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you can't : I just confirmed this via some test code.

```
PS > javac -version
javac 1.6.0_04
```

**Casts.java**

```
public class Casts
{
    public static <From, To> To cast(final From object)
    {
        return (To)object;
    }
}
```

**Test.java**

```
import static Casts.cast;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final Integer integer = new Integer(5);

        // This one compiles fine.
        final Number number = Casts.<Integer, Number>cast(integer);

        // This one fails compilation:
        // PS> javac Test.java
        // Test.java:11: illegal start of expression
        //             final Number number = <Integer, Number>cast(integer);
        //                                                    ^
        // Test.java:11: not a statement
        //             final Number number = <Integer, Number>cast(integer);
        //                                                        ^
        final String string = <Integer, String>cast(integer);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar with the same results.  But I can't find anything in the JLS that suggests that the second form *should* be invalid.

Comment: Thanks! Just one suggestion, it will be better if the method cast is implemented like this:

    public <From, To extends From> To cast(final From object)

I discussed it here:

http://satukubik.com/2010/01/06/java-tips-using-generic-correctly/

Comment: Yea... I don't know WHY specifying the generic parameters causes this to happen. Just know experimentally that it does. I think static imports are the devil anyway, so I would never have known this otherwise. :)

Comment: @nanda Yes, that would be a better specification, as it prevents the possibility of a run-time `ClassCastException`, generating a compiler error instead.

Comment: @nando Note that `From` needs to extend `To` though. I tried specifying it as `<From, To super From>`, but the compiler does not like that so much. It does accept `<To, From extends To>` though.

Comment: @Dan Dyer: you must search the JLS to find if it is valid: JLS-15.12 shows what is accepted

Comment: @jdmichal: I think you're wrong... <To, From extends To> means there is no casting at all (from subtype to supertype, always correct), <From, To extends From> means casting (from supertype to subtype, may still wrong, which is the essence of casting).

Comment: @nanda Ah. I only accounted for up-casting, not down-casting. (It's still casting, even if there's no chance of error.) You would need to make both up-cast and down-cast methods to accommodate both situations using parameter wildcards.

Answer (score 9):

### No

If you want to provide an explicit type parameter when calling a generic static method, you must prefix the method with the class name, even if the method is statically imported.

Answer (score 5):

Java grammar allows type arguments only with typename specified. See corresponding section in JLS https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-MethodInvocation

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the answer is no--if you want to use a generic method call, you need an object to call it on (`foo.<T>doSomething()`).  If the method is static, you need the class ( `Foo.<T>doSomething()` ).

This is even true if you're calling the method from elsewhere in the class itself.  If you are working in a non-static method (i.e. in an instance method), you would call `this.<T>doSomething()`.

Comment: almost everything in this answer is incorrect
1) You can definitely call static methods without using the class if the method is statically imported
2) You can call static methods on an object or a class, though the former is considered a bad practice
3) You do not need to prefix a static method with the class name within a class

Comment: Yes, you can if you are not declaring the casting class within the generic brackets <>.  If you do want to declare the cast, you need an object.  Show me it working without.

Comment: + 1 for mentioning this problem is not specifically related to static imports.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I've read, a shortcoming of the static import mechanism is that you must specify the calling object/class if you wish to provide formal parameters. In this example, it's not very clear why there are two generic parameters, but if you wish to avoid having to specify the calling object/class you can type hint through a cast of the arguments as such:

```
public static <E> E foo(E e) {}

Number n = foo((Number)3);
```

With the type hint, the type inference will return an object of type Number, instead of Integer as it would have reasoned otherwise.

Comment: Actually, public static <E> E foo(Object obj) { return (E) obj; }; Number n = foo(3); works as well, tho you prolly need to suppress some warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct. I end up writing small methods that basically work as typed aliases for the generic.

For example:

```
private static TheGenericClass<Number> foo(OtherGeneric<Number> value) {
    return TheGenericClass.foo(value);
}
```

Note that this method looks perfectly redundant, and effectively it is. It's only needed because of a limitation of how Java does generics and how it doesn't let you do aliasing in import statements.