# Generics Java and Shadowing of type parameters

Tags: java, generics

This code seems to work fine

```
class Rule<T>
{

    public <T>Rule(T t)
    {

    }
    public <T> void Foo(T t)
    {

    }
 }
```

1. Does the method type parameter shadow the class type parameter?
2. Also when you create an object does it use the type parameter of the class?

example

```
Rule<String> r = new Rule<String>();
```

Does this normally apply to the type parameter of the class, in the situation where they **do not conflict?** I mean when only the class has a type parameter, not the constructor, or does this look for a type parameter in the constructor? If they **do conflict** how does this change?

**SEE DISCUSSION BELOW**

if I have a function call

```
x = <Type Parameter>method(); // this is a syntax error even inside the function or class ; I must place a this before it, why is this, and does everything still hold true. Why don't I need to prefix anything for the constructor call. Shouldn't Oracle fix this.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All of your `T`s are different, but you can only see it if you call your methods with the [complete syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html):

For example, this code is valid:

```
new <Float>Rule<Integer>().<Character>Foo();
```

Just to make this easier to explain, let's assume your code is this:

```
class Rule<A>
{

    public <B>Rule()
    {

    }
    public <C> void Foo()
    {

    }
 }
```

Then you can explicitly declare generic types like:

```
new <B>Rule<A>().<C>Foo();
```

If the types have the same name, the inner-most one will be chosen (the `T` on the method, not the class):

With this code, taking parameters:

```
class Rule<T>
{

    public <T>Rule(T t)
    {

    }
    public <T> void Foo(T t)
    {

    }
}
```

Then this is valid:

```
new <Float>Rule<Integer>(3.2f);
```

Note that `T` in the constructor is `Float`, not `Integer`.

Another example:

```
class Example<T> {

    public <T> void foo1() {
        // T here is the <T> declared on foo1
    }

    public void foo2() {
        // T here is the <T> declared on the class Example
    }
}
```

I found another question that deals with [calling methods with explicit generic types without something before them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050317/invoking-statically-imported-method-with-explicit-type-parameters). It seems like static imports and same-class method calls are the same. It seems like Java doesn't let you start a line with `<Type>` for some reason.

Comment: Very cool :-), so when you say the inner most would be chosen, just to confirm the most rightward one would be chosen?

Comment: @rubixibuc - No, the one on the method will be chosen. To explicitly declare a generic type on a method, you put it first (`x = <GenericType>callFunction()`). With a class, you put it after the name of the class when you construct it (`new ArrayList<String>()`). If you want to do both, you put the generic type for the constructor first, then the generic type for the class after (`new <GenericTypeForConstructor>MyClass<GenericTypeForClass>()`).

Comment: Also inside the constructor all T references refer to Flose, and outside they refer to Integer?

Comment: @rubixibuc - Yes, unless another method overrides `T` (like `Foo` does).

Comment: It seems that is a syntax error "illegal start of expression"

Comment: @rubixibuc - In which one? My first example assumes your original code (no parameters).

Comment: The call to a generic method with a explicit generic parameter type, when I call inside it's own function it still needs an explicit this call.

Comment: I read somewhere the explicit parameters for methods always need to be prefixed with a class or object even within the function themselves, is this true?

Comment: The call to the constructor worked as is, I just wanted to make sure I'm making the call right and everything stays the same

Comment: I'll add it into the question because I'm not sure how to do formatting for code in the comments

Comment: @rubixibuc - You'd need to post your code for me to understand what's going wrong. Your problem might be that you're trying to use `T` as a variable (it's not -- it actually disappears at compile time).

Comment: I added the comment to the bottom of the question

Comment: @rubixibuc - Most likely the parser just can't handle statements that start with `<`. There's [another question on here that deals with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050317/invoking-statically-imported-method-with-explicit-type-parameters).

Answer (score 1):

> Does the method type parameter shadow the class type parameter?

The `<T>` declaration on constructor is not referred to class type. So yes, it shadow the class type parameter.

In this case it is used as a generic type param that you can use with the constructor, for example as argument. Try this constructor:

```
public <P> Rule(P arg1, P arg2) {    
}
```

As you can see I define a type `<P>` and then I use it to be sure that the arguments will be of type `P`. In your case you are declaring a type that will be valid for the constructor without using it.

Look at this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html).

> Also when you create an object does it use the type parameter of the class?

Every generic type definition has is scope as a variable. So out of the constructor returns valid the class type.