# Java generics, type variable scope

Tags: java, generics, compareto

What's the difference between:

```
public <E>int  compareTo(E e) // first line (compilation error)
```

and

```
public int compareTo(E e) // second line (OK)
```

only in the second line i get through the compiler. Does it mean that it needs to be sure that that particular element is universally declared within the class?
Otherwise you could put in any element and would not make much sense. Am I seeing it in the right way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us more of your code (in particular, what's `E`)?

Comment: Aside: your first example is meaningless, because of erasure it's the same as `public int compareTo(Object e)`. (Valid uses of type parameters on methods usually need the type parameter to be used in two places, establishing a constraint between parameters and/or the return type.)

Comment: @Perception Type parameters shadow one another: http://ideone.com/i3GXx8 (It's probably a good idea to avoid that though.)

Comment: @millimoose +1, that is correct.

Comment: @everybody Whatever element I put before the return type it gives me an error as though it would not override properly the method signature.

Comment: @Rollerball Don't say "an error", say which error. If the error is a *different* one than the one before, you should accept the answer that helped you resolve your original problem. If it's a different problem than people have guessed, then you should expand your question to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public <E extends String> int compareTo(E o) {  //1
}
```

You can consider any class instead of `String` as per your programming need.

Above scenario is considered for a class which is implementing `Comparable` interface.

```
class SimpleClass<E> {  // 2
    E var;  
    public <E> int compareTo(E o) {         
        return 0;
    }
}
```

above  class at //2 will work if we don't implement `Comparable` interface. **E** need not extend String(any other class).

Comment: It's not *necessary* for the type parameter to be constrained.

Comment: how do we write then ? `public <E> int compareTo(E o) {}` throws compile time error. User is curious about writing <E> somewhere near to return type so is my answer :-)

Comment: @Rollerball Your question really really really should've included the fact that you're implementing `Comparable<String>` if you indeed are doing that.

Comment: @millimoose `public <E> int compareTo(E o) {}` throws exception even if we have return statement.

Comment: @AmitG ...huh? ( http://ideone.com/i3GXx8 works for me, can you provide a test case? )

Comment: @millimoose  above scenario is considered for Comparable interface. What you are doing is also correct. Try to create class which will implement Comparable interface. User has given `compareTo` method and above scenario works in comparable interface implementation.

Comment: @AmitG Yeah, I was considering the method signature in isolation. The question could really stand some improvement.

Answer (score 2):

Put the type parameter declaration  before the return type:

```
public <E> int compareTo(E e)
```

You can have a class level `<E>` type parameter as well, but the method level parameter will shadow it. Read more about it in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10151077/1276804).

Comment: @zagyl Edited as you suggested, (typing error) but still it does not work. It behaves like if the method signature does not get overridden properly

Comment: @zagyl furthermore I cannot even put a <P> or any other letter.

Comment: @Rollerball If you're implementing an interface method that's a whole new problem. Your `compareTo()` method still has to be compatible with the declaration from the interface.

Comment: If all you want to do is to implement `Comparable`, then you don't need to make the method generic. Why do you want to use a type parameter on `compareTo()`?