# Generic method with no parameter

Tags: java, generics

I create a generic method without parameter, some thing like:

```
private <T> TableCell<T> createTableCell(){
return new TableCell<T>();
}
```

So, in my program, how to call this method for a concrete type?

Comment: once you will call this method , it will return the TableCell of Type T ie T holds the type of the class

Comment: Did you mean "return" instead of "Return"?

Comment: Generally, when I call this method, it will return TableCell<Object>, but I want to cast it into a concrete type, called Class A and B. So how to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590405/generic-method-in-java-without-generic-argument

Comment: @Kafray: you're right, my typo. I updated it.

Comment: @Sottile: that's an option, but not what you want. I can achieve this by adding a dummy parameter into my method, but that's not really make sense.

Comment: In certain limited circumstances, Java *can* actually infer the correct type for T without all the extra syntax.  In particular, if you're assigning the result to a variable of type `TableCell< SomeTypeOrTypeVariable >`,  `TableCell< ? extends SomeTypeOrTypeVariable >`, or `Table< ? super SomeTypeOrTypeVariable >`, Java infers `SomeTypeOrTypeVariable` for `T`.  If you are using `createTableCell()` as a top level call without using the result, Java infers `Object` for `T`.  It's only when you try to nest the call to `createTableCell()` inside another expression that Java gives up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Usually, the type is inferred, but you can specify the type with this syntax:

Note: You have an error in your method's definition - it had no return type:

```
private <T> TableCell<T> createTableCell(){
    return new TableCell<T>();
}
```

Here's how you can call it:

```
TableCell<SomeType> tableCell = myObject.<SomeType>createTableCell();
```

If you method doesn't access any fields, consider making it a `static` method, which you would call like:

```
TableCell<SomeType> tableCell = MyClass.<SomeType>createTableCell();
```

As an aside, when you use this syntax, many will marvel at your "eliteness" - it's a syntax not often seen.

Comment: yes, your're right. This's my mistake.
Anyway, the generic method is in a non-generic class, and I want other method of this class call this generic class, not method of other class.

Comment: Yes. I also posted the correct answer first. (The other answer was edited after mine was posted - I think he copied mine). nm.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it helps me to understand clearer, as syntax in defining generic class vs generic method make me confused.

Comment: Can you explain more about: "the type is infered", why calling <SomeType>createTableCell() does not work, while this.<SomeType>createTableCell() does?

Comment: @Thinhbk The reason is technical: the java compiler does not accept statements that start with special character (in this case `<`), and would require a lot of changes in the compiler(grammar) to implement it.

Comment: @Bohemian _>>>I think he copied mine_  --- Hmmm, you can easily check the diff of the edits. But i will give you my +1 since you need score so much

Comment: @OpDeCirkel I went by the timestamp of my post vs the timestamp of the comment that altered you to your typo. You see that missingfaktor's comment was one minute *after* my post (which I got right first time). +1 to you too :)

Comment: @Bohemian Before discrediting somebody try to verify your argument

Comment: @OpDeCirkel OK, I'm going to put things straight. Your edit to correct the typo was at `05:27:30`. My first post (which was correct) was at `05:26:02`, almost 1.5 minutes *before* your edit. Therefore you *may* have copied my correct answer. Are we cool?

Answer (score 7):

Because the type can not be inferred from the context (when you call the method) you have to specify it when calling in the folowing way:

```
obj.<MyType>createTableCell()
```

where `obj` is the object of a class/type that contains that method.

Comment: Actually the syntax is `obj.<MyType>createTableCell()`.

Comment: @missingfaktor yes. thanks. I was actually trying it in meantime because i always forget the syntax in that case ... you were faster then me

Comment: @Thinhbk Do not rush accepting answers, it is possible that somebody provides more accurate and deeper explanation later on.

Answer (score -2):

You'd call this method the same way you called the constructor inside it: `createTableCell<TypeName>()`.

Comment: Hmm, in that case you would have to extend the method signature to include a type hint. The usual way to do that if you don't really have anything relevant to pass into the method is a `Class<T>` parameter that exists for the sole purpose of specifying the type. You'd then call the method as `createTableCell(TypeName.class)`.