# Java generics compile in Eclipse, but not in javac

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, compiler-construction, javac

I had to discover I have Java code in my project, which compiles and runs fine in Eclipse, but throws a compilation error in javac.

A self-contained snippet:

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> setOfInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Set<Object> setOfObjects = covariantSet(setOfInts);
    }

    public static <S, T extends S> Set<S> covariantSet(Set<T> set) {
    return new HashSet<S>(set);
    }

}
```

Compilation in javac returns:

```
Main.java:10: incompatible types
found   : java.util.Set<java.lang.Integer>
required: java.util.Set<java.lang.Object>
    Set<Object> setOfObjects = covariantSet(setOfInts);
                                           ^
```

This error now prevents building the project in Maven. As the Eclipse compiler is built to be more tolerant, I now have to assume the definition and usage of snippets as above static method is no valid Java?

Comment: Could it be that they are using different versions of the JDK (say Java 6 vs Java 7 for example) and this would be a bug in older JDK versions?

Comment: I use javac 1.6.0_37, and Eclipse Helios with compiler compliance level 1.6.

Comment: FYI I just tested your code and it compiles with Java 7 but not with Java 6.

Comment: @assylias Thanks, this is a helpful information. Wonder why that is exactly...

Comment: Are you aware that the `T` is unnecessary for `covariantSet` as it is here? (`covariantSet(<Set<? extends S> set)` is equivalent -- unless of course your actual method is more complex and uses `T` somehow, although I at the moment can think of no good example where the difference of `S` and `T` would be relevant.)

Comment: @arne.b I hope i understand you correctly - you mean substituting the method with `public static <S> Set<S> covariantSet(Set<? extends S> set) { return new HashSet<S>(set); }`? Unfortunately this does not compile in neither EJC nor javac 1.6.x.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to point out that `T` is redundant in this simple case. Also, Raffaele's answer still applies and you need to specify one explicit type parameter less if the method has only one. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that Sun's 1.6 JDK can't infer the correct type. The following seems to work on my machine:

```
Set<Object> setOfObjects = Main.<Object, Integer>covariantSet(setOfInts);
```

Note that you must invoke the static method [prefixed with the class name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590405/315306)

Comment: Accepting this answer, since it provides the least intrusive workaround to solve the stated problem.

Answer (score 10):

You are right. This problem indeed exists. Eclipse does not use `javac`. It uses its own compiler.

Actually javac is "right". Generics are erasures. Type `S` is not included into your byte code, so jvm does not have enough information about the return type at runtime. To solve the problem change the method prototype as following:

`public static <S, T extends S> Set<S> covariantSet(Set<T> set, Class<S> returnType)`

Now the return type is passed to the method at runtime and compiler should not complain.

Comment: It seems to compile ok with javac / JDK 7

Comment: Your solution works as described. I was suspecting type erasure to be cause. Interestingly though, as assylias mentioned above, it seems to compile in java 7.

Comment: @mtsz that would mean that java 7 improved on the generic inference

Comment: I think it is a bug in JDK 6. as AlexR mentioned generics are erasures. But that also means that the Set does not need the information of beeing of type <S> at runtime. Hence the quasi equivalent after comilation is simply
`Set setOfObjects = Main.covariantSet(setOfInts);` No need of generics at all. And for compile time the generic types should be injected correctly just like the eclipse compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

In your Maven build skript you have set the compiler version.

In Ant it lookes like this:

```
<property name="source.version" value="1.5" />
```

search for 1.3 or 1.4, or compile to find that value in the maven skripts

With value 1.5 the compiler will accept the generics (see your error messages)

Comment: It appears to be recognizing generics just fine, though.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the java source and target-version of maven-compiler-plugin to 1.5 does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old question, but I want to mention, the function could be written as:

```java
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> setOfInts = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Set<Object> setOfObjects = covariantSet(setOfInts);
    }

    public static <S> Set<S> covariantSet(Set<? extends S> set) {
        return new HashSet<S>(set);
    }

}
```

It's a little bit cleaner and you can use the function exactly how you intented to(with implicit generic typing).

Answer (score -1):

Add the next plugin to your pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.3.2</version>
     <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
     </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I've tried your snippet which denotes an older version of the maven-compiler-plugin. It does not help. I am using the most current version 2.5.1