# Java generics with wildcard compile in Eclipse, but not in javac

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, wildcard, javac

As a follow up to [Java generics compile in Eclipse, but not in javac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13533880), I post another snippet which compiles and runs fine in Eclipse, but raises a compilation error in javac. (This prevents the project the snippet is extracted from, from being build with Maven.)

The self-contained snippet:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Foo<?>> setOfFoos = new HashSet<Foo<?>>();
    List<Foo<?>> sortedListOfFoos = asSortedList(setOfFoos);
  }


  public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
  }


  public static class Foo<T> implements Comparable<Foo<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo<T> o) {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation in javac returns:

```
Main.java:11: <T>asSortedList(java.util.Collection<T>) in Main cannot be applied to (java.util.Set<Main.Foo<?>>)
    List<Foo<?>> sortedListOfFoos = asSortedList(setOfFoos);
                                    ^
```

On substitution of `Foo<?>` with `Foo<String>` the above snippet will compile in javac, which means the problem is related to the used wildcard. As the Eclipse compiler is supposed to be more tolerant, is it possible the snippet is no valid Java?

(I use javac 1.6.0_37 and Eclipse Indigo with compiler compliance level 1.6)

(**EDIT1:** Included another example which got removed in EDIT2.)

**EDIT2:** Hinted by [irreputable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535825/691083), that comparing `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>` may be conceptually wrong, and inspired by the answer of [seh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13535813/691083), a working `asSortedFooList` can be written as follows:

```
public static <T extends Foo<?>> List<T> asSortedFooList(Collection<T> c) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

(Simple substitution of `Comparable<T>` with `Foo<?>` in the method definition above.)
So it seems to be safe for javac and imho conceptually right to compare any `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>`. But it is still not possible to write a generic method `asSortedList` which returns a sorted list representation for a generic collection, if its type argument is parametrized with a wildcard. I tried to "trick" javac by substituting `Foo<?>` by `S extends Comparable<S>` in `asSortedFooList`, but this didn't work.

**EDIT3:** Later [Rafaelle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543272/691083) pointed out, that there is a flaw in the design, since implementing `Comparable<Foo<T>>` is not necessary, and implementing `Comparable<Foo<?>>` provides the same functionality, solving the initial problem by refined design.

(The initial reason and benefit was, that a `Foo<T>` may not care *in some purposes* about its concrete type but still use an instance of a concrete type `T`, it is instantiated with, for other purposes. That instance does not have to be used for determining the order among other `Foo`s, as it may be used in other parts of the API.

Concrete example: Assume each Foo is instantiated with a different type argument for `T`. Every instance of `Foo<T>` has an incrementing id of type `int` which is used in the implementation of the `compareTo`-method.  We can now sort a list of these differently typed `Foo` and don't care about the concrete type `T` (expressing it with `Foo<?>`) and *still* have an instance of a concrete type `T` accessible for later processing.)

Comment: What happens if you tell Eclipse to specifically use the jdk compiler ?

Comment: @Jerome this can be done? I can adjust settings of the compiler and select the JRE but I could not find about a possibility to select the compiler itself.

Comment: @mstz I may be mistaken. You can indeed select a JRE, not sure at all about the jdk and his compiler

Comment: You are reasoning that `Foo<A>, Foo<B>` can be compared due to erasure. Erasure is a current implementation workaround; it is possible that future Java gets rid of erasure, so all generic info are available at runtime. In any case, the static analysis does not involve erasure.

Comment: @mtsz I didn't say that `Foo` should not be parameterized, since that depends on what `Foo` is in your program. I said that the **formal parameter** of `Foo.compareTo(other)` doesn't benefit from using a type variable. You can still parameterize `Foo` and implementing `Comparable<Foo<?>>`, so that your code compiles and you have the same functionality (and even backward compatibility)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this is another `javac` bug. When you try to send a `Collection<Foo<?>>` to a method with the signature:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c)
```

the compiler notes that the *formal parameter* `T` has an upper bound, so checks if the constrained is honored by the caller. The *type argument* is a (wildcard) instantiation of the parameterized type `Foo<T>`, so the test will pass if `Foo<?>` *is-a* `Comparable<Foo<?>>`. Based upon the generic definition:

```
class Foo<T> implements Comparable<Foo<T>>
```

I'd say that it's true, so again Eclipse is right and `javac` has a bug. This [Angelika Langer's entry](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ201) is never linked enough. Also see [the relevant JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.10.2).

You asked if it is type-safe or not. My answer is that it **is type safe**, and it shows you have a flaw in your design. Consider your fictitious implementation of the `Comparable<T>` interface, where I added two more fields:

```
public static class Foo<T> implements Comparable<Foo<T>> {

  private T pState;
  private String state;

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Foo<T> other) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

You always return `0`, so the problem is not spotted. But when you try to make it useful, you have two options:

1. Comparing on the String field
2. Comparing on the `T` member

The `String` field is always a `String`, so you don't really benefit from the type variable `T`. On the other hand, `T` has no other type information available, so in `compareTo()` you can only deal with a plain object, and again the type parameter is useless. You can achieve the same exact functionality by implementing `Comparable<Foo<?>>`

Comment: Thanks for your insights. I will study the JLS and Ms. Langer's explanation, thanks for linking to it. Regarding your argument about the flawed design: I've updated my question with further information and a concrete example, why such a design may have a benefit (at least for me).

Comment: Maybe *flawed design* is too much. I'd have better said *suboptimal*. The point is you can't do anything useful with the `T` variable inside `compareTo()`, so you can safely implement `Comparable<Foo<?>>` and javac will be happy to compile :)

Comment: You are right, it is a flaw, I didn't read it carefully enough, especially your last line! Implementing `Comparable<Foo<?>>` instead of `Comparable<Foo<T>>` does the job, I've should have seen it earlier, but didn't :)

Comment: I would like to accept your answer, because it provided useful insights about the initial problem and solved my design flaw.

Comment: I don't think you have to ask permission to accept an answer :P

Answer (score 2):

In this case, javac is correct. Conceptually, your code can't work, since the set may contain `Foo<A>` and `Foo<B>`, which can't be compared to each other.

You probably want the set to be a `Set<Foo<X>>` for some type variable X; unfortunately we can't introduce type variable inside method body; only in method signature

```
<X> void test(){
    Set<Foo<X>> setOfFoos = new HashSet<Foo<X>>();
    List<Foo<X>> sortedListOfFoos = asSortedList(setOfFoos);
}
```

You may make it work by something like

```
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) 


class Foo<T> implements Comparable<Foo<?>>
```

Comment: Please see my proposed solution which does just that: it introduces a type variable for `Foo<X>` using an otherwise unnecessary intermediary method.

Comment: wildcard capture only works on 1st level; in this example the wildcard is on the 2nd level.

Comment: If Eclipse compiles it, there must be a rationale, and if we find it we can get `javac` to compile too. It's not a compiler's purpose to tell if it's conceptually right or wrong: I find misleading to use human concepts like *set* and *contain* when explaining generics. The compiler is a dumb program that can only check if a sequence of tokens follows the Java rules. It doesn't understand semantics like *container type* and *contains*

Comment: I'm also a dumb program that can check if the code follows language spec. I can also reason that the code violates type safety, so it can't work, since Java is type safe.

Comment: @irreputable I've edited the question to discuss the type (un)safety of such a definition. I can see why it is type safe to prohibit such definitions, but I am not able to see right now where it gets unsafe when you allow them (meaning it may be to strict).

Comment: I never said you are wrong, just wanted to encourage you to improve your answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a question, but here is a (not very nice) answer:
If you sacrifice some type safety you can write

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public static <T extends Comparable> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
}
```

And it works in both eclipse and javac. The only risk that I'm aware of is that if someone creates a `class Foo extends Comparable<Bazz>` you won't detect that in compile time.
But if someone creates `Foo extends Comparable<Bazz>`, just kill him/her.

Comment: My first question is, if it is valid Java, and if not, any analogous solution is welcome. Your solution compiles, and has the risk you have foreseen. The class can be made final, so nobody should get harmed :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that compiles with *javac*, though I am not happy that I am unable to explain exactly why it works. It requires introducing an intermediary function:

```
public final class Main {
  public static class Foo<T> implements Comparable<Foo<T>> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Foo<T> o) {
      return 0;
    }
  }


  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
  List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
    final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    return list;
  }


  private static <T extends Foo<?>> List<T> asSortedFooList(Collection<T> c) {
    return asSortedList(c);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Set<Foo<?>> setOfFoos = new HashSet<Foo<?>>();
    final List<Foo<?>> listOfFoos = asSortedFooList(setOfFoos);
  }
}
```

I *think* that this works by virtue of taking the wildcard resolution step-by-step; `asSortedFooList()` captures one type known to be a `Foo`, irrespective of `Foo`'s type parameter. With that type parameter bound in `asSortedFooList()`, we can then call on your original `asSortedList()` (well, with one modification—note the lower bound on the type parameter for `Comparable`) requiring binding `Foo` as a type descended from `Comparable`.

Again, that's a weak, haphazard explanation. My main point in answering here is just to provide one more way to get to your destination.

Comment: @seh If I understand your solution right, you substituted `main` and added the method `asSortedFooList`, leaving the rest of my snippet unaltered? If I do as described, I get in Eclipse an compilation error `Bound mismatch: The generic method asSortedList(Collection<T>) of type Main is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<T>). The inferred type T is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T 
 extends Comparable<T>>`. javac does not work as well. Would you please provide your complete solution? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I neglected to include the slightly-modified `asSortedList()` with a newly-added lower bound on its type parameter. Please try the additional code included in my answer and let us known if Eclipse accepts it.

Comment: Yes, Eclipse and its compiler EJC did accept it, thanks. Inspired by your answer, I managed to make my solution compile by applying `T extends Foo<?>` to the signature of `asSortedList` directly, which works similar to your solution but using only one method. I've edited my question to provide additional information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can replace your wildcard usage with an exact type (which may be a super-type) your code will work. Replace

```
List<Foo<?>> sortedListOfFoos = asSortedList(setOfFoos);
```

with

```
List<Foo<String>> sortedListOfFoos = Main.<Foo<String>>asSortedList(setOfFoos);
```

Comment: Giving -1 without a comment is lame.

Comment: I am not dovnwoter but you probably got -1 because your answer doesn't solve OP problem (I may be mistaken since I just tested it with Java 7 compilator and OP is using version 6)

Comment: I don't get it, he wanted the code to compile and it does make it compile.

Comment: I've tried your proposed approach before, as it was provided in the linked question already. Unfortunately it does not work in this case. Your version of IDEA uses javac 1.6.x?

Comment: There is normally a difference of explicitly giving the arguments so it was not exactly as given. But it was still not a correct answer. The problem is with the wildcard operator. Change that to String and it works. I even tried with a manual javac command! :)

Comment: Thanks, I've noticed that it is the wildcard. I've mentioned it at the end of the question, as I did the same test as you :) That is what puzzles me, because I don't see why the wildcard does have such an impact.