# Java casting with primitive wrappers - difference between Java 6 and Java 8

Tags: java, casting, wrapper, primitive

I came across this piece of legacy code (Java 6) (that's simplified version that pinpoints my issue):

```
Object o;
o = new Long (3L);
Double d;
d = (Double) o;
```

This one above is obviously not working as wrappers can be cast only to corresponding primitive types. I fixed this by:

```
Long toConvert = (Long) o;
String convert = toConvert.toString();
d= Double.parseDouble(convert);
```

and it works fine, except being ugly. I tried another solution:

```
d = (double) o;
```

and I worked as well, but when I checked this solution (pure curiosity) in new Java 8 project I got

*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double*

Does Java 6 differs from Java 8 when it comes to primitive wrappers in a way that can explain observed behaviour?

Comment: Are you working with Javac? Or the Eclipse compiler (ECJ)?

Comment: Here is a question about a thing that sounds relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120861/is-casting-from-number-to-double-allowed-in-java-7-autoboxing (maybe it is a duplicate). Apparently the behaviour of casts changed somewhat in Java 7.

Comment: Thank you, i wouldn't say it's duplicate, but I'm sure it's relevant!

Comment: The question about which compiler you use is also important! The linked question mentions that Javac and the Eclipse compiler has differences here. And exactly which versions do you use?

Comment: Interestingly, if `o` is of type `Long`, the conversion succeeds...